# ViewBag Mvc4 Error

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, viewbag

I am new in MVC4 vb.net. I faced this error when I run my program.

"MissingMemberException was unhandled by user code.

Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Chars' accepts this number of arguments."

Hereby shows my code:

HelloWorldController.vb

```
    Public Function Welcome(name As String, Optional numTimes As Integer = 1) As ActionResult
        ViewBag.Message = "Hello" & name
        ViewBag.NumTimes = numTimes

        Return View()
    End Function
```

Welcome.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <%ViewBag.Title = "Welcome"%>

  <h2>Welcome</h2>
  <ul>
     <%For i = 0 To ViewBag.NumTimes-1%>
        <li> <%ViewBag.Message()%> </li> //error 
  <%Next i%>
  </ul>

</asp:Content>
```

Please explain to me why this will happen. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `<%ViewBag.Message()%>`

Change it to `<%= ViewBag.Message %>`.

Comment: Thank you very much. LOL. kind of embarrasses to make this tiny mistake. Perhaps i need some time to familiar with the syntax. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where `Chars` is coming from, but it should be `ViewBag.Message` and not `ViewBag.Message()` as it is a property, not a function.

Comment: `Chars` is the "default property" of `String` in VB.NET, `ViewBag.Message` is a `String` instance. `()` is VB's indexing operator (in addition to the method-call operator) but no arguments were specified, hence the complaint. This would work, however: `<%= ViewBag.Message(0) %>` (which would print the first character in the string). It's also why I don't like VB :)